# Is there any way to set the value of the net_read_timeout flag in google cloud sql?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

This particular flag (net_read_timeout) is not available in the list of settable flags from the cloud console, nor is it mentioned in the documentation (https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags). I can see the currently set value for this flag by executing:

```
show global variables like '%timeout%';
```

Which shows:

```
| net_read_timeout                          | 30       |
```

Setting this flag from the command line is not supported:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL net_read_timeout=120;
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

So I was wondering if there is any way to change the value of this flag.

Answer (score 1):

Since the net_read_timeout flag is not listed as a [Supported Tag](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags#list-flags) in Cloud SQL, you cannot change it through any channel (console, command line or API). However, if you have a paid support package or are currently under free trial, it may be worth asking, through a support case, if something can be worked out.

You may also create a feature request through this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187202&template=1010842), for this flag to be supported in future releases. Just keep in mind this doesn't guarantee whether it will be included or when.

Comment: Thanks, I added a feature request as suggested.